# URL rewrite (routing), mod_rewrite, or PHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, friendly-url

Was trying to sort it out by myself but no luck.

I have a website (PHP, Apache),  with the following structure, as a sample:

```
1. http://hostname/ 
2. http://hostname/category?list=listname 
3. http://hostname/product?id=...&name=productname 
4. http://hostname/recipes 
5. http://hostname/recipe?id=...&name=recipename

+ many others.
```

Current .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

So for examples http://hostname/category?list=...  becomes /category.php?list...
And then it catches php script and works.

I want to make friendly URLs like these:

```
1. http://hostname/ 
2. http://hostname/category/listname/
3. http://hostname/product/productname/
4. http://hostname/recipes/
5. http://hostname/recipe/recipename/
```

And on the other hand previous urls must still work as webiste is hugely indexed by search enginges.  So from oldstyle urls it must 301 redirect to new urls.
Any ideas?
All my efforts had errors. I even tried to make PHP routing via index.php entry point,  but i cant get how to deal with oldstyle links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, disable `multiviews` if it is enabled. Try the following rules to enable 301 redrects to new url structures:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(category|product|recipe)(?:\.php)?\?.*(name|list)=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%3/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

As for the local/internal redirects back to actual pages, that'd have to be dealt with individually:

```
RewriteRule ^(category)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?list=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(recipe|product)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?name=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(recipe)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for help.  `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (category|product|recipe)(?:\.php)?\?.*(name|list)=([^&\s]+) [NC]`  works only without ^GET\.   can't disable multiviews, hosting settings do not allow doing this. everything else works as it suppose to.  What makes [NC] and [L]  in these cases?

Comment: `NC` means matching capital/small-case letters alike. `L` means do not process further rules. Read more about flags here: https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/rewrite/flags @Zergius2 I had missed the leading `/` in that `RewriteCond`.